# Can I use netlify's CDN to prevent lambda execution more than once a day?

Tags: http, cache-control, netlify

I have a Netlify deployed app with a lambda function that calls an external API to get some data. The external API data is updated once a day, and I'd like the lambda response to be cached in Netlify's CDN for 24 hours, so I don't invoke the lambda function, and thus call the external API, more than once a day.

To test this, I wrote a simple lambda function:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: new Date().toString(),
    headers: {
      'Cache-Control': 'public, s-maxage=86400',
    },
  });
};
```

When calling the endpoint a second time after 10 seconds, I do get the same time in the response so body, indicating that the response was indeed cached. 
But when calling it from two different devices (my computer and my 4G phone, so different IPs and ISPs), I get different dates, as if each device was served a different cached response, and I can see in Netlify's dashboard that the lambda was invoked twice.

Is there something I don't understand about how Netlify's CDN works?
Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer:  I work for Netlify and would give you the same answer in the helpdesk.

The short answer is, no, you can't quite do this as you're intending, and yes, there are probably some things about the CDN that you don't understand.  Read on to learn :)

Your intuition on setting the `Cache-control` header is correct about how to affect Netlify's caching, and should do what you are trying to do! However, its effects would be limited to a single CDN node, and Netlify has dozens of CDN nodes (and several separate CDN's, but that isn't in play here).

Each CDN node handles its own caching, so while the response is cached (in this case for a day), it is cached only on a single CDN node.  Your phone and computer, or even your computer and the same computer 1 second later, could talk to a different CDN node with every page load due to the way Netlify handles load balancing.

So - what your implementation would accomplish is not necessarily "return cached content on second+ load for next 24h" but "fetch content no more often than `# of CDN nodes Netlify has in rotation` times per day if the content is used constantly".  That condition "used constantly" sounds weird - but Netlify runs a caching CDN and does not have infinite cache capacity, so your results may not STAY in cache for the whole day if enough other content is more recently requested.

If you want to accomplish your stated goal - load data only once per day from API - you should load it to somewhere persistent and fetch it from there in your function.

But I think your intended goal is actually "avoid refetching the data constantly" and your implementation should work for that purpose. :)